# How to detect the NAT type without using STUN?

Tags: networking, nat

I would like to detect the NAT type a network interface is behind, without using an external public server, as it's done in STUN (so, without using STUN clients).

The NAT types I am interested are those as defined in http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3489.txt, section 5 '5.  NAT Variations'.

Answer (score 2):

The bad news is you can't (I am assuming you don't have the telephone numbers of all the network administrators managing all the NATs you plan to deal with).

In order to find the type of a NAT, you must have a device poking holes from behind on the LAN to the WAN.